# ffmpeg mix audio at specific time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I want to mix 2 audio files together - one file has a length of 2 mins and the other is a 10 second sound. I want both files to mix so both sounds can still be heard. I want this 10 second clip to come in exactly at 30 seconds for the 10 seconds so it will end at 40 seconds.

I know how to mix 2 audio files together using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

However, I do not know how to start this 10 second sound at a specific time.

Comment: should be moved to SuperUser.com as there's a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/716320/ffmpeg-placing-audio-at-specific-location-with-complex-filters

Comment: Thanks for this but that solution did not work for me as i need to keep the file in a mp4 format

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After posting this question, I've found a solution to this problem.
First, create a blank audio file longer than the longest clip using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=mono -t <seconds> -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame <blank audio>
```

After the blank audio file has been created, add the shorter, second clip at the desired time.

```
ffmpeg -i <blank audio> -i < audio file 2> -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d= <time> [s1];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[aout]" -c:v copy -map 0:v -map [aout] <output file>
```

Then overlay the first, longer clip to the original clip.

```
ffmpeg -i <output from silent and short clip> -i <original long clip> -filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0, volume=2" <output audio file>
```

Comment: can I do all of this in one line?

Comment: I tried it but your second script is cliping blank audio upto the lenght of short audio. I have many audio files which I want to combine at specific time. There for running your script in loop like`ffmpeg -y -i file.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=0[s1];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[aout]" -c:v copy -map [aout] file.mp3`

Comment: I got this error: `zsh: no matches found: [aout]`

Comment: I had to remove `-map 0:v` in the 2nd command.

Answer (score 1):

My audio sample rate is 8000. I used the following command without synthetic audio to insert 3 audio files at specific times. Please note that delays in seconds have to be integers. For a precise position, you can use 'S' (Sample) instead of 's' (second) to define delays.

```
ffmpeg -y -i earth.mp4 -i 1.wav -i 2.wav -i 3.wav -filter_complex "[1]adelay=delays=5s:all=1[r1]; [2]adelay=delays=8000S:all=1[r2]; [3]adelay=delays=15s:all=1[r3]; [r1][r2][r3]amix=inputs=3[a]"  -map 0:v -map "[a]" -codec:v copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Error: [Parsed_adelay_0 @ 0x558a843524c0] Option 'all' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x558a8427d600] Error initializing filter 'adelay' with args 'delays=5s:all=1'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found