# NodeJS video streaming transcode on the fly

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming

I'm building a nodejs app that streams a video from the disk to the user. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976123/streaming-a-video-file-to-an-html5-video-player-with-node-js-so-that-the-video-c#) question, i have a working video feed for a "static" video file that is stored on disk, so far so good.

My problem is that i need to transcode the video on the fly, to do this i used fluent-ffmpeg and i was successful at implementing the transcoding, but the HTML5 player only shows the first 3-4s of the video, and then stops. I'm guessing the problem is the filesize, but even when i harcode it nothing changes.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot :)

```
var file = 'Big_Buck_Bunny_1080p_surround_FrostWire.com.mp4';
    fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
        var range = req.headers.range
        if (!range) { // 416 Wrong range
            return res.sendStatus(416)
        }
        var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
        var total = stats.size;
        var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
        var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

        res.writeHead(206, {
            "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            "Content-Length": chunksize,
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
        })

        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start: start, end: end, autoclose: true })
        .on("open", function() {
            const ffmpegCommand = ffmpeg()
                .input(stream)
                .outputFormat('mp4')
                .outputOptions([ '-movflags faststart', '-frag_size 4096', '-cpu-used 2', '-deadline realtime', '-threads 4' ])
                .videoBitrate(640, true)
                .audioBitrate(128)
                .audioCodec('aac')
                .videoCodec('libx264')
                .output(res)
                .run()
        }).on("error", function(err) {
            res.end(err)
        })
    })
```

Comment: I don't believe you can use `output` here, you need to use a `pipe`. See this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483191/stream-overlapping-audio-files-to-chromecast-audio/50016463#50016463

Comment: Also, the http response contains `Content-Range`, `Content-Length` headers which include information about the size of the **original** video, not the transcoded one, which might be significantly different. When transcoding on the fly you should probably not set these at all if you cannot reliably determine them in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the best solution i found was to use a more "streaming-friendly" format, so i switched to HLS and now everything is simpler and works just fine :)

Comment: you mean from the client side ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should drop `.output(res)
                .run()`

and use `.stream().pipe(res, { end: true})` instead